# Run code inside a do block? (Active Admin Dashboard)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

**Active Admin Dashboard**

```
  ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do

  menu :priority => 1, :label => proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }

  content :title => proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do

    section h2 "Top Movie" do

            table_for @top_ps.where('ptype = ?', 'movie') do |t|

               column("Title"){|p| link_to p.title, admin_program_path(p.id)}

               column "Start" do |p|

                    p.program_schedules.each do |schedule|

                            link_to distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, schedule.start,true), admin_program_schedule_path(schedule.id)
                    end

                end


            end
        end

  end # content
end
```

If I run this i get

```
[#<ProgramSchedule id: 746, program_id: 430, start: "2012-09-17 09:30:00", stop: "2012-09-17 10:30:00">, 
#<ProgramSchedule id: 8124, program_id: 430, start: "2012-09-22 23:30:00", stop: "2012-09-23 00:30:00">]
```

Instead of

```
<a href="/path">Start</a>
<a href="/path">Start</a>
```

I understand where I am wrong, but how to execute that code inside a block?

Comment: how this templating language is called? :) I forgot

Comment: Is this HAML? I thought Rails used ERB, but maybe it can use both. When embedding with ERB you have to use <%= %> to actually output the result of the Ruby code.

Comment: No, it's just Ruby code. I've just updated the post with the whole code. (It come from Active Admin)

Comment: ah, this is ActiveAdmin DSL. It would be nice to state this in the title and tags I believe

Comment: yes, you're right. I did it ;)

Comment: @khustochka Do You know how to do in ActiveAdmin DSL?

Comment: No, I have never used this gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This template DSL is called Arbre.  I'm not sure if it's used much outside of ActiveAdmin.  With the release of ActiveAdmin 0.5.0 it's been split off into it's own gem https://github.com/gregbell/arbre

If you don't want to deal with it you can render a partial. So in your dashboard code put something like

```
section h2, "Top Movie" do
  div do
    render :partial => "admin/dashboard/top_movie"
  end
end
```

And then

```
# /views/admin/dashboard/_top_movie.html.erb

<div style="width:300px;">
  Normal arbitrary view code. <%=some_ruby%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`= link_to distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, schedule.start,true), admin_program_schedule_path(schedule.id)` or

`<%= link_to distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, schedule.start,true), admin_program_schedule_path(schedule.id) %>` depending on whether its haml or erb respectively.

Comment: This is for HAML and ERB. But seems topic starter uses Slim http://slim-lang.com/

Comment: No, it's just Ruby code. I've just updated the post with the whole code. (It come from Active Admin)